# How to affordably release a webapp for my job company

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web-applications, hosting

First of all, I'm not really sure if this question goes here in stackoverflow or if I should ask it on another place. Please if that's the case, indicate me in the right way :)

So, for context, this is an app that I was asked to develop for my job. At first I thought in doing a webapp and host it inside the company servers and domain (intranet), but it isn't possible due to external issues that I can't control.

Is there another way to achieve this? The app must have a database and should be accessible for a bunch of users at the same time.

Of course we want to spend the least amount of money possible to make this happen. Also, using a workstation of our own to host everything is not possible either.

---

Edit: I didn't finish developing, but for now I'm developing it in Python Flask.
The number of users is small really, just up to five people.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I guess a lot of what you'll get in response to this is your definition is too vague. Things such as scale, number of users, programming languages used to create the web app etc are important when talking about hosting.

However, for me, there are three very good options out there for free hosting, up to a certain amount of traffic.

1.) Heroku - Heroku.com

A world known web hosting platform. You can publish code through GitHub, and it has some extensive coverage for different types of web apps. Definitely worth a look.

2.) Netlify - netlify.com

Similar to Heroku, but used by some major companies. Allows you to host for free to a point, and is relatively simple to get started with.

3.) Vercel - vercel.com

A bit more technical in my opinion - but again, very similar to the above two and has a free tier.

All three are great options, and I'd recommend looking into them in more detail to see what option is best for you. Can't go wrong with any of them.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I will look check them out. Also, I edited my question. The language I'm currently using is Python with Flask, and the quantity of users is small, like up to five people.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: A Python-Flask-SQLite app for me and my office pals to use together.
The solution was creating one .exe file with pyinstaller, hosting this and the database files in a network drive (one that everyone that will use the app has access). As everybody (~10 people) sees the same db, things works fine!